# AppEngine with Restlet handling requests, NullPointEerexception with DomRepresentation response

Tags: google-app-engine, restlet

After deploying my App Engine app and doing a POST request that is supposed to return XML, I get the following error:

```
org.restlet.engine.http.HttpServerAdapter commit: An exception occured writing the response entity
java.io.IOException: Couldn't write the XML representation: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.restlet.ext.xml.DomRepresentation.write(DomRepresentation.java:275)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.HttpServerCall.writeResponseBody(HttpServerCall.java:510)
```

Doing the exact same request on the app ran locally does not cause any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have data in your local db, that is not accessible in the deployed version? Please give some more background information (code, libraries), if that is not it.

Comment: Yes, sorry this was a terrible question but I have figured it out now. It was some null data in the data store that went unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a GAE issue with chunked encoding. There is now a workaround in Restlet 2.1 M3. See the related question:
[Restlet POSTing JSON to Appengine error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051397/restlet-posting-json-to-appengine-error)